# beginner's tutorial for report viewer?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + SQL Server 2008 + ASP.Net + IIS 7 to develop web application. Any quick and easy to learn tutorial for report viewer -- I want to generate report based on data from SQL Server 2008. Basic design and implementation function is fine, no need to learn advanced topics about report reviewer at this time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd recommend starting here:

- http://www.gotreportviewer.com/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179197%28SQL.80%29.aspx

**UPDATE**

Take a look at [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataSetReports04252007100945AM/DataSetReports.aspx), it provides step by step details. It uses a dataset instead of a database but you should be able to make the necessary adjustments fairly easily.