# Test that Microsoft Report Viewer is working?

Tags: .net, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

Is there any simple way to test that an installation of report viewer redistributable 2008 is working properly?

I've been tasked with making sure this piece of software is functioning correctly, but given no further instructions.

How would I go about testing this? .NET tools aren't what I've normally used, so I'm at a complete loss here!

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this link  : [beginner's tutorial for report viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110643/beginners-tutorial-for-report-viewer)

You can also use resources from MSDN, such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms251669(v=vs.90).aspx