# C# Organize Data Onto a Print Template

Tags: c#, templates, printing, format

Ok I've tried this in every possible combination...  I know this can be done in Access, so I know it can be done in C#...

What I'm trying to do is set up a print button, that when clicked, organizes data from various controls on my form into specific positions on a predefined template.  Like say I'm generating a Job Estimate, and I want to print it...  It would look silly printing the control or form, so I'd like it organized into a neat standard format on a page, that may include a logo etc.  I don't want the data exported to a document, I just want the print button to auto-generate this so that it can be printed from the application.

Can anyone point me to some resource that deals with this?  I have googled my mind away, and searched all over stack overflow, but I'm not even sure what the correct wording to look something like this up with is, as it keeps giving me c++ or some other random stuff to look at that has nothing to do with what I am looking for....

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a reporting tool, which can render a structured report to screen, or to print or to a file format like PDF.

Many reporting tools exist for .Net development, Crystal Reports, Active Reports, Reporting Services in SQL Server.

Comment: So the reportviewer control would accomplish this?

Comment: This answer has some tutorials on Report Viewer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110643/beginners-tutorial-for-report-viewer You may need to evaluate various reporting tools to see what suits your requirements.